# Keeping track of asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a Mozilla extension, and have a problem where I make n calls to an asynchronous function, that function is out of my control and it executes a callback on completion. In this callback, I need to take a special action if it's the n'th & final callback. I can't work out how to determine if a callback is the final one, I thought about setting a counter and decrementing it each time, but due to the nested loop I don't know in advance how many async calls will be made (without working it out in advance which would be inefficient). Any ideas on an elegant approach to this?

```
function dataCallBack(mHdr, mimeData)
{
    // ... Do stuff ...
    // Was this the final callback? 
}

function getData() {
    var secSize = secList.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < secSize; i++) {
        if (secList[i].shares.length >= secList[i].t) {

        var hdrCount = secList[i].hdrArray.length;

        for(var j = 0; j < hdrCount; j++)
        {
                    // MAKE ASYNC CALL HERE
            mozillaFunction(secList[i].hdrArray[j], this, dataCallBack);
        }
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something along these lines:

```
   var requestsWaiting = 0;
   // this will be the function to create a callback
   function makeDataCallback() {
     requestsWaiting++; // increase count
     // return our callback:
     return function dataCallBack(mHdr, mimeData)
     {
       // ... Do stuff ...
       // per request - make sure that this happens in the next event loop:
       // can be commented out if not needed.
       setTimeout(function() {
         // Was this the final callback? 
         if (! --requestsWaiting) {
            // it was the final callback!
         }
       // can be commented out if not needed
       },0);
     }
   }

// then in your loop:
// MAKE ASYNC CALL HERE
mozillaFunction(secList[i].hdrArray[j], this, makeDataCallBack());
```

Comment: thank you. That looks good, but is it possible that a callback could be executed before the next iteration of the loop? i.e create callback -> callback executed -> is_final, all before the next loop iteration is made. Or is it guaranteed that requestsWaiting will remain > 0 until the last function call in the loop?

Comment: @Jason Gooner - Yeah, you could actually wrap the if in a `setTimeout(function(){` ... `},0);` to combat that, will edit in when not on my phone :)